# Certbot renew running but not renewing - 2021

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have exactly the same issue as this post 3 years ago. Certbot timer is working, but the cert will not renew every 90 days. I resorted to booting the server and the cert will be updated. I have also shown my certbot system status and certbot.service. Previously, it was mentioned that this could be due to permission, but it is unlikely since the cert is updated upon reboot. What could be the problem here? Thank you.

[]
[1]: [Certbot renew running but not renewing](https://serverfault.com/questions/946680/certbot-renew-running-but-not-renewing)

```
super@mail:~$ sudo systemctl status certbot
● certbot.service - Certbot
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/certbot.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2021-09-06 15:21:02 +08; 2h 42min ago
     Docs: file:///usr/share/doc/python-certbot-doc/html/index.html
           https://letsencrypt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
 Main PID: 19282 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 06 15:21:01 mail systemd[1]: Starting Certbot...
Sep 06 15:21:02 mail systemd[1]: certbot.service: Succeeded.
Sep 06 15:21:02 mail systemd[1]: Started Certbot.

super@mail:~$ cat /lib/systemd/system/certbot.service
[Unit]
Description=Certbot
Documentation=file:///usr/share/doc/python-certbot-doc/html/index.html
Documentation=https://letsencrypt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/certbot -q renew
PrivateTmp=true
```

Comment: Please make sure you are not using certbot from the Ubuntu apt repositories. [Only use the certbot _snap_ on Ubuntu](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntufocal-nginx).

Comment: Does your system use port 80 for another web application? What kind of challenge do you use?

Comment: What is in certbot logs?

Comment: My server OS is Debian and I did not use certbot snap.  I will install certbot snap after I solve this issue.

Comment: Port 80 not used for another web application. I use http-01 challenge.

Comment: Log
2021-07-18 02:59:19,901:DEBUG:certbot.storage:Writing new private key to /etc/letsencrypt/archive/ooo.ooo.com/privkey10.pem.
2021-07-18 02:59:19,902:DEBUG:certbot.storage:Writing certificate to /etc/letsencrypt/archive/ooo.ooo.com/cert10.pem.
2021-07-18 02:59:19,902:DEBUG:certbot.storage:Writing chain to /etc/letsencrypt/archive/ooo.ooo.com/chain10.pem.
2021-07-18 02:59:19,902:DEBUG:certbot.storage:Writing full chain to /etc/letsencrypt/archive/ooo.ooo.com/fullchain10.pem.
2021-07-18 02:59:19,924:DEBUG:certbot.storage:Writing new config /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/ooo.ooo.com.conf.new.

Comment: Is it because I did not restart nginx?